# Like Count by author

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

I'm looking to build a wordpress site with multiple authors that will each be posting content that viewers can then "like".

What I am trying to figure out is if it would be possible to somehow keep a track on the number of likes each author is getting in total.

Would the best way to do this be too just have multiple Apps with different ID's and somehow generate the like code dynamically based on the Author or is there a smarter way to do it ?

Once I have this in place how hard would it be to pull the counts into an HTML widget to display a kind of league table of most liked authors ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to achieve this with the JavaScript SDK and the Like callback.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

But you will have to record those likes into your database and pull count from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so what this does is basically triggers an event on like to record the data in the local Wordpress DB ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't help you with connecting this to Wordpress. That's another category :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ref parameter of the like plugin if you don't have easy access to do what Alexander recommended (If you can store the data yourself it's better as you can really make your own data analysis).  But here's the out-of-the-box way Facebook provides for tracking where a like came from.

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

> **ref** - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some
>   punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes two
>   parameters to be added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link
>   from a stream story about a Like action:
>
> - **fb_ref** - the ref parameter
> - **fb_source** - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'ticker', 'tickerdialog' or 'other') in which the click occurred and
>     the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an
>     underscore.

Comment: This feels like a nice easy option that I may be able to achieve with my limited skills ! Will go have a test, many Thanks !

Comment: Good to hear.  Take your time, you will get it.